# SharePoint 2013 web part to display logged in claims user

Tags: sharepoint-server

Depending on who has logged in I have to display a corresponding N/w folder in a webpart,this is forms based login
my username is email address shouldnt I be getting `c:0-.f|customroleprovider|walmart@walmart.com` , instead I get `sharepoint\system`

```
        ClientContext clientContext = new ClientContext("http://sp2013/");
        clientContext.ExecutingWebRequest += new  EventHandler<WebRequestEventArgs>(clientContext_ExecutingWebRequest);
        Web web = clientContext.Web;
        clientContext.Load(web);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        clientContext.Load(web.CurrentUser);
        clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
        var currentUser = clientContext.Web.CurrentUser.LoginName;
        string username = currentUser.ToString();

        if (username == "walmart@walmart.com")
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\supplier\walmart");
            this.PopulateTreeView(dirInfo, null);

        }

        else
        {
            DirectoryInfo dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"\\supplier\target");
            this.PopulateTreeView(dirInfo, null);

        }

 private void PopulateTreeView(DirectoryInfo dirInfo, TreeNode treeNode)
{

    foreach (DirectoryInfo directory in dirInfo.GetDirectories())
    {
        TreeNode directoryNode = new TreeNode
        {
            Text = directory.Name,
            Value = directory.FullName
        };

        if (treeNode == null)
        {
            //If Root Node, add to TreeView.
            TreeView1.Nodes.Add(directoryNode);
        }
        else
        {
            //If Child Node, add to Parent Node.
            treeNode.ChildNodes.Add(directoryNode);
        }

        ////Get all files in the Directory.
        //foreach (FileInfo file in directory.GetFiles())
        //{
        //    //Add each file as Child Node.
        //    TreeNode fileNode = new TreeNode
        //    {
        //        Text = file.Name,
        //        Value = file.FullName,
        //        Target = "_blank",
        //       // NavigateUrl = (new Uri(Server.MapPath("~/"))).MakeRelativeUri(new Uri(file.FullName)).ToString()
        //    };
        //    directoryNode.ChildNodes.Add(fileNode);
        //}

        PopulateTreeView(directory, directoryNode);
    }
```

Comment: check this one http://yuriburger.net/2011/04/14/sharepoint-claims-web-part/

Answer (score 0):

I guess SharePoint (WebApplication Pool and other Services) are running under your account. Then your account is the System-Account and that´s the Information SharePoint delivers to you.

Comment: Once i deploy the webpart and a FBA user logs in , will it show the logged in person ? in the above case is either walmart@walmart.com or target

Answer (score 0):

this solution worked for me 
 IClaimsPrincipal cp = Page.User as IClaimsPrincipal; //SharePoint claims 
                if (cp != null)
                {

```
                IClaimsIdentity ci = (IClaimsIdentity)cp.Identity;
                foreach (Claim c in ci.Claims)
                {
                    if (c.ClaimType == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)
                    {

                        username = c.Value;
```